# my Random number generator always returning zeros

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int random;

    public void createRandomNum() {     // Function than creating random number

        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(21);

    }

    public void guess(View view) {

        EditText guess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        int guessInt = Integer.parseInt(guess.getText().toString());
        String message;
        if (guessInt == random) {

            message = "congo!!";

        }
        else if (guessInt > random) {

            message = "Lower!!";

        }
        else {

            message = "Higher!!";

        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        createRandomNum();       //calling createRandomNum() function

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createRandomNum();   //calling that function
    }
}
```

//after running it in android emulator it always guessing the value Zero

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep creating a new Random each time. Create it once and use it to create new numbers.

Comment: Do you really need all of those blank lines in your code?  (You should read a Java style guide ....)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new local variable `int random` in the `createRandomNum` method rather than setting the existing one.

You probably meant:

```java
random = rand.nextInt(21);
```